# What are the rules for plotting directed graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Say I have an ordered pair of sets. One contains the vertices and the other - edges.

What are the rules for actually plotting the graphs with these givens? Can a graph be plotted differently given the same set of vertices and same set of edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no rules for plotting graphs.  As long as you have a dot for each vertex and a line for each edge, and the edges connect the appropriate vertices as indicated by the edge set of the graph, it doesn't matter how the graph is drawn.